# Problems with Binding a socket on a remote machine

Tags: java, linux, sockets, snmp, snmp4j

Need help from you big time. I'm stuck up with an issue for over 2 days now and haven't been able to find a solution even in google!!

Anyway, I'll just post my problem below. Please help me at the earliest

***Problem***

I've been trying to develop an SNMP agent using an API called Friendly SNMP(it is a wrapper around Snmp4j) and things were great initially as everything was smooth. Now, when I'm trying to send traps/notifications to a remote machine which is in my system's network, i'm getting a pretty frustrating Bind Exception with a message "Cannot assign requested address". Here is the stacktrace.

2011-06-08 14:25:30,180 - org.friendlysnmp.FException - ERROR - Failure to init SNMP agent
[1] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:373)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:229)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:282)

However, everything works well if I use localhost/127.0.0.1 as the IP address where the traps are sent. Creepy that!!

***Attempts at Solving***

1) I've done a netstat to see if the port is already bound and apparently the port is free. So, this is out of question.

2) I've pinged the remote host, done a telnet and everything is working.

3) There are a lot of discussions which have mentioned that we need to set some options in JVM to use IPv4 address by default. I've done this, but no luck

4) I've tested this on a Windows machine and no success.

So, please help me guys, i'm stuck here. Let me know if I need to make some changes in the /etc/hosts file or something.

I'm attaching my properties file(where i specify the IP address) and the log file for reference.

PS : Oh, and please ignore the way I specify the IP and port in the properties file, that is how the API expects it.

PS2 : Unfortunately, I'm unable to attach any file. So, please find the log below.

```
2011-06-08 13:59:20,252 - org.friendlysnmp.FriendlyAgent - DEBUG - Loaded prop: {snmp.plugin.log4j=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.log4j.PluginLog4j, snmp.v3.password.priv=/M3o0zp3Q+0g/BgRRoetGQ==, snmp.v3.protocol.priv=DES, snmp.storage.vacm.viewtree=readOnly, snmp.plugin.jvm=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.jvm.PluginJVM, snmp.v2.community=public, snmp.address.send-notification=10.155.10.228/1162, snmp.persist.filename=DemoFriendly.bin, snmp.plugin.heartbeat=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.heartbeat.PluginHeartbeat, snmp.storage.vacm.group=readOnly, snmp.v3.password.auth=TumNjJ34uUA8XapXe3SYOQ==, snmp.v3.protocol.auth=SHA, snmp.storage.notify=readOnly, snmp.ignore-update-ms=1000, snmp.storage.vacm.access=readOnly, snmp.address.get-set=10.155.10.228/1161}
2011-06-08 13:59:20,253 - org.friendlysnmp.FriendlyAgent - INFO - === STARTED FriendlyAgent ===
2011-06-08 13:59:20,306 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - INFO - Created agent at 10.155.10.228/1161; Notify to 10.155.10.228/1162; EngineID=80:00:71:a3:01:ac:10:01:76
2011-06-08 13:59:20,308 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - IgnoreUpdate: 1000 ms
2011-06-08 13:59:20,309 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorageImpl - DEBUG - Storage filename 'DemoFriendly.bin'
2011-06-08 13:59:20,323 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorageImpl - INFO - Loaded persist file: /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/DemoFriendly.bin
2011-06-08 13:59:20,324 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorage - DEBUG - Persistency policy: ON_CHANGE
2011-06-08 13:59:20,324 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - Transport: UDP
2011-06-08 13:59:20,325 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - TransportDomain: IPV4
2011-06-08 13:59:20,329 - org.friendlysnmp.target.TargetBase - DEBUG - Created target 'public' SecModel=0 MsgProcModel=0 SecLevel=0
2011-06-08 13:59:20,331 - org.friendlysnmp.target.TargetBase - DEBUG - Loaded target 'public': storageVacmGroup=readOnly storageVacmAccess=readOnly storageVacmViewTree=readOnly storageNotify=readOnly notifyTimeout=1000 notifyRetryCount=1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,331 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - INFO - Added Target: TargetV2 TARGET=public
2011-06-08 13:59:20,344 - org.friendlysnmp.plugin.log4j.PluginLog4j - DEBUG - Found log4j props: /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/src/log4j.properties
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appConfigEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appDependenciesEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appInfoEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appPropEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: deadlockViewEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: deadlocksListEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,401 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: exceptionViewEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,402 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: exceptionsListEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,402 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistCellEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,402 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistScalarEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,402 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistTableEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,402 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: sysPropEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,404 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.3.0 'shutdownApp' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,405 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.3.3.1 'persistScalarEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,406 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.3.4.1 'persistTableEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,411 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.30.0 'deadlockCheckInterval' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 13:59:20,411 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.30.0 'deadlockCheckInterval': 1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,412 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.32.0 'deadlockViewPolicy' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 13:59:20,412 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.32.0 'deadlockViewPolicy': 1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,413 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.33.0 'deadlockViewFixedIndex' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,415 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.20.0 'exceptionViewPolicy' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 13:59:20,415 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.20.0 'exceptionViewPolicy': 1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,416 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.21.0 'exceptionViewFixedIndex' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,417 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.10.1 'exceptionsListEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,423 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: log4jLoggerEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,423 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: log4jPropEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,424 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.10.1.0 'log4jPropFile': /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/src/log4j.properties
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemGCEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemManagerEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemMgrPoolRelEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemPoolEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTBootClassPathEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTClassPathEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,451 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTInputArgsEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,452 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTLibraryPathEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,452 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmThreadInstanceEntry
2011-06-08 13:59:20,453 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.1.4.0 'jvmClassesVerboseLevel': 1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,457 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.2.0 'jvmMemoryGCVerboseLevel': 1
2011-06-08 13:59:20,458 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.3.0 'jvmMemoryGCCall' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,465 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.5.0 'jvmThreadContentionMonitoring': 4
2011-06-08 13:59:20,467 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.6.0 'jvmThreadCpuTimeMonitoring': 4
2011-06-08 13:59:20,468 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.7.0 'jvmThreadPeakCountReset' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 13:59:20,478 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - DEBUG - Transport=UDP
2011-06-08 13:59:20,486 - org.friendlysnmp.FException - ERROR - Failure to init SNMP agent
[1] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:373)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:229)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:282)
2011-06-08 14:25:29,901 - org.friendlysnmp.FriendlyAgent - DEBUG - Loaded prop: {snmp.plugin.log4j=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.log4j.PluginLog4j, snmp.v3.password.priv=/M3o0zp3Q+0g/BgRRoetGQ==, snmp.v3.protocol.priv=DES, snmp.storage.vacm.viewtree=readOnly, snmp.plugin.jvm=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.jvm.PluginJVM, snmp.v2.community=public, snmp.address.send-notification=10.155.10.228/162, snmp.persist.filename=DemoFriendly.bin, snmp.plugin.heartbeat=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.heartbeat.PluginHeartbeat, snmp.storage.vacm.group=readOnly, snmp.v3.password.auth=TumNjJ34uUA8XapXe3SYOQ==, snmp.v3.protocol.auth=SHA, snmp.storage.notify=readOnly, snmp.ignore-update-ms=1000, snmp.storage.vacm.access=readOnly, snmp.address.get-set=10.155.10.228/161}
2011-06-08 14:25:29,902 - org.friendlysnmp.FriendlyAgent - INFO - === STARTED FriendlyAgent ===
2011-06-08 14:25:29,968 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - INFO - Created agent at 10.155.10.228/161; Notify to 10.155.10.228/162; EngineID=80:00:71:a3:01:ac:10:01:76
2011-06-08 14:25:29,972 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - IgnoreUpdate: 1000 ms
2011-06-08 14:25:29,973 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorageImpl - DEBUG - Storage filename 'DemoFriendly.bin'
2011-06-08 14:25:29,991 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorageImpl - INFO - Loaded persist file: /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/DemoFriendly.bin
2011-06-08 14:25:29,991 - org.friendlysnmp.persist.PersistStorage - DEBUG - Persistency policy: ON_CHANGE
2011-06-08 14:25:29,992 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - Transport: UDP
2011-06-08 14:25:29,992 - org.friendlysnmp.FConfig - INFO - TransportDomain: IPV4
2011-06-08 14:25:29,997 - org.friendlysnmp.target.TargetBase - DEBUG - Created target 'public' SecModel=0 MsgProcModel=0 SecLevel=0
2011-06-08 14:25:29,999 - org.friendlysnmp.target.TargetBase - DEBUG - Loaded target 'public': storageVacmGroup=readOnly storageVacmAccess=readOnly storageVacmViewTree=readOnly storageNotify=readOnly notifyTimeout=1000 notifyRetryCount=1
2011-06-08 14:25:29,999 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - INFO - Added Target: TargetV2 TARGET=public
2011-06-08 14:25:30,012 - org.friendlysnmp.plugin.log4j.PluginLog4j - DEBUG - Found log4j props: /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/build/classes/log4j.properties
2011-06-08 14:25:30,079 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appConfigEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appDependenciesEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appInfoEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: appPropEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: deadlockViewEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: deadlocksListEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: exceptionViewEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: exceptionsListEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistCellEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,080 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistScalarEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,081 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: persistTableEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,081 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: sysPropEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,083 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.3.0 'shutdownApp' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,084 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.3.3.1 'persistScalarEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,086 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.3.4.1 'persistTableEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,091 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.30.0 'deadlockCheckInterval' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 14:25:30,091 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.30.0 'deadlockCheckInterval': 1
2011-06-08 14:25:30,092 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.32.0 'deadlockViewPolicy' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 14:25:30,092 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.32.0 'deadlockViewPolicy': 1
2011-06-08 14:25:30,093 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.33.0 'deadlockViewFixedIndex' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,096 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.20.0 'exceptionViewPolicy' Volatile=false
2011-06-08 14:25:30,096 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.20.0 'exceptionViewPolicy': 1
2011-06-08 14:25:30,096 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.21.0 'exceptionViewFixedIndex' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,098 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.2.10.1 'exceptionsListEntry' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,106 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: log4jLoggerEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,106 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: log4jPropEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,106 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.29091.1.1.1.10.1.0 'log4jPropFile': /home/vishwas/NetBeansProjects/SocketProgramming/build/classes/log4j.properties
2011-06-08 14:25:30,138 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemGCEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,138 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemManagerEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,138 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemMgrPoolRelEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,138 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmMemPoolEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,139 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTBootClassPathEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,139 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTClassPathEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,139 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTInputArgsEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,139 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmRTLibraryPathEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,139 - org.friendlysnmp.FTable - DEBUG - Created table: jvmThreadInstanceEntry
2011-06-08 14:25:30,141 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.1.4.0 'jvmClassesVerboseLevel': 1
2011-06-08 14:25:30,145 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.2.0 'jvmMemoryGCVerboseLevel': 1
2011-06-08 14:25:30,147 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.3.0 'jvmMemoryGCCall' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,156 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.5.0 'jvmThreadContentionMonitoring': 4
2011-06-08 14:25:30,157 - org.friendlysnmp.FScalar - DEBUG - Updated 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.6.0 'jvmThreadCpuTimeMonitoring': 4
2011-06-08 14:25:30,158 - org.friendlysnmp.FValueNode - DEBUG - 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.7.0 'jvmThreadPeakCountReset' Volatile=true
2011-06-08 14:25:30,171 - org.friendlysnmp.AgentWorker - DEBUG - Transport=UDP
2011-06-08 14:25:30,180 - org.friendlysnmp.FException - ERROR - Failure to init SNMP agent
[1] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:373)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:229)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:282)
```

**Properties file is below**

```
# NOTE: Some of the values below are defined as SET nodes and
# might be overwritten by MIB manager and persist between sessions.
#
# See FConstant class for full list of valid entries in the properties.

# Address of THIS application to respond on SET and GET requests
# The address 161 might be already used by Windows SNMP service.
snmp.address.get-set=10.155.10.228/161

# Address to send notifications
snmp.address.send-notification=10.155.10.228/162

# Plugins
snmp.plugin.jvm=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.jvm.PluginJVM
snmp.plugin.log4j=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.log4j.PluginLog4j
snmp.plugin.heartbeat=org.friendlysnmp.plugin.heartbeat.PluginHeartbeat

# Disallow application boots count reset.
# The entry is optional. Default value is true.
#snmp.allow-boots-count-reset=false

# Local engine ID.
# The entry is optional. This value overrides default generated value.
# NOTE: This value for SNMPv3 must match target EngineID in MIB browser
# (if it is set not empty)
#snmp.engine-id=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08

# Heartbeat interval (seconds).
# This is interval in seconds how often heartbeat notifications are sent.
# The entry is optional. Default value is 0 sec.
# This value is ignored if it is set explicitly from MIB browser.
#snmp.heartbeat-interval-sec=60

# FriendlySNMP might receive multiple GET NEXT with subrequests
# for the same SNMP object in a short period of time. Each
# of these requests would fire update event. The application
# might want to coalesce duplicate update events into a single
# one. If identical update events are received in the
# following time frame only a single update event will be fired.
# Allowed values are 0 .. 10,000 ms.
# The entry is optional. Default value is 1000 ms.
snmp.ignore-update-ms=1000

# Root OID for views.
# These entries are optional. Default values are "1.3".
#snmp.oidroot.notify-view=1.3
#snmp.oidroot.read-view=1.3
#snmp.oidroot.write-view=1.3

# Thread pool size.
# The entry is optional. Default value is 4.
#snmp.thread-pool-size=4

# Filename to store serialized default persistence storage.
# The entry is optional. Default filename is generated from main app classname.
snmp.persist.filename=DemoFriendly.bin

# Transport. Valid values are: UDP or TCP.
# The entry is optional. Default value is UDP.
#snmp.transport=UDP

# Transport domain. Valid values are: IPV4, IPV4Z, IPV6, IPV6Z.
# The entry is optional. Default value is IPV4
#snmp.transport.domain=IPV4

# Storage type.
# MIB StorageType TC: Describes the memory realization of a conceptual row.
# A row which is volatile(2) is lost upon reboot. A row which either
# nonVolatile(3), permanent(4) or readOnly(5), is backed up by stable storage.
# A row which is permanent(4) can be changed but not deleted. A row which is
# readOnly(5) cannot be changed nor deleted.
# If the value of an object with this syntax is either permanent(4) or
# readOnly(5), it cannot be written. Conversely, if the value is either
# other(1), volatile(2) or nonVolatile(3), it cannot be modified to be
# permanent(4) or readOnly(5).
# Upper or lower case is ignored.
# These entries are optional. All defaults are "readOnly"
snmp.storage.vacm.group=readOnly
snmp.storage.vacm.access=readOnly
snmp.storage.vacm.viewtree=readOnly
snmp.storage.notify=readOnly

# Notification timeout.
# The entry is optional. Default value is 1000 ms.
#snmp.notify.timeout-ms=1000

# Notification retry count.
# The entry is optional. Default value is 1 time.
#snmp.notify.retry-count=1

# List of v1/v2 communities separated by spaces, e.g. "public snmp"
#snmp.v1.community=public
#snmp.v2.community=public snmp
snmp.v2.community=public

# List of v3 users separated by spaces, e.g. "john craig"
#snmp.v3.user=friend

# Security section for v3.
# These values are not used until "snmp.v3.user=.." entry is specified.
# Authentication and privilege passwords (passphrases) should be encoded
# using the FriendlyPro tool with the specified or default key.
# Valid auth protocols: none, MD5, SHA
# Valid priv protocols: none, DES, AES128, AES192, AES256
# Default protocols are "none" or define empty value for "none".
# Decrypted passwords: "SHAAuthPassword" and "DESPrivPassword"
snmp.v3.protocol.auth=SHA
snmp.v3.protocol.priv=DES
#snmp.v3.password.key=friendly
snmp.v3.password.auth=TumNjJ34uUA8XapXe3SYOQ==
snmp.v3.password.priv=/M3o0zp3Q+0g/BgRRoetGQ==

# Uncaught exceptions are handled by agent and their stack traces are not
# shown by JVM in a console. Set this value to "true" in development
# environment to see stack traces and to "false" in production to keep
# console clean.
# The entry is optional. Default value is "true".
#snmp.console-uncaught=false

# Persistency policy. The entry is optional.
# Valid values are "on_change" and "on_exit". Default value is "on_change"
#snmp.persist.policy=on_change
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vishwas

---

@all --> thanks for your help...i resolved the problem...there were some configuration errors. I corrected the same. Everything's fine now. Thank you all again

Comment: Which setting in that properties file is it that causes the problem ? (it sounds like the real problem is that you or the library is trying to bind() a socket to a remote address, which you can't do. you bind() to any local addresses, and you connect() or sendto() a remote address)

Comment: Can you post the code that does the bind() call?

Comment: @nos : from my observation, it is the IP address and Port part which is causing the problem. Ya, sorry that I didn't put it the right way. Binding only happens on the localhost.

Comment: @Jim Garrison : The bind() call is made by the API i'm using, so not sure where that happens. But, one thing I can say is that when I'm initializing the snmp agent, an exception is being thrown.

agentSNMP = new FriendlyAgent(TITLE, VERSION, propApp);
agentSNMP.init(); //Problems here!!
agentSNMP.start();

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you're trying to bind to a non-local ip address. You aren't meant to use bind like that. You're meant to bind to an ip address on the machine that the program is running on. Your obversation 'creepy that' that it works when you use the localhost address shouldn't come as a surprise because that's what is meant to work.

Comment: correction, I didn't put it the right way. Like you said, I'm binding to a port in the local system but sending the packets to the remote system. However, as per the API, I need to specify the IP address and Port number of the remote system in the properties file which I've clearly done. Not sure why I'm getting this exception. Might be a problem with the API?

Comment: @all --> thanks for your help...i resolved the problem...there were some configuration errors. I corrected the same. Everything's fine now. Thank you all again.